# how to retrieve the value of the star clicked in a jquery star rating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, rating

I am using a jquery star rating plugin.the link is [here] (http://irfandurmus.com/projects/jquery-star-rating-plugin/).
[here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtIW7.png)

I have a table in which one column have a star rating to rate  an item. I am looping the star rating to rate the item present in all rows.I need to get the value of star clicked in each row . However i couldn,t get the value of star clicked in each row. please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with Javascript:

```
jQuery('.star').on("click", function(){
  var rating = jQuery(this).attr('title');
});
```

Comment: thanks it worked.would you suggest a method to store this value into a database and sort according the value

Comment: @doej Glad it helped you! :)

Comment: @doej Nope, sorry :( But you can ask a new question with proper tags and updated code!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$('td .rating-div').each(function(){
   console.log($('.stars').find('a.fullStar.star').length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
$('.rating-div').each( function() { 
    console.log( $(this).find('> .stars > .fullStar:last').attr("title")  ) 
} );
```